# Chained Templates in Angular

Tags: angular, templates

Just learning Angular2/4 so please bear with me...

Assume I have a **CoursesComponent** which has a list of **CourseComponent**s. The *HTMLTemplate* for **CoursesComponent** simply iterates the **CourseComponent** (list) field and displays each course.

I want the **CourseComponent** to handle the display of course with it's own *HTMLTemplate*.

**CourseComponent HTMLTemplate** *(with selector:'course')*

```
<div class='course'>
{{title}}({{code}})
<br/>
{{description}}
</div>
```

**CoursesComponent HTMLTemplate** *(with selector:'courses')*

```
<div class='courses'>
<ul>
<li *ngFor='let c of courseList'><course></course></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**AppComponent HTMLTemplate**

```
<div>
<courses></courses>
</div>
```

How do you achieve this? Is it even possible? Can templates be chained in this fashion?

Comment: don't use angularjs tag for anything but angular 1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **CoursesComponent** html file add can add you variable like this

```
<div class='courses'>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let c of courseList'>
    <course [data]="c"></course>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then You have to add a input variable in your **CourseComponent** ts file

```
@Input() data: any = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this snippets

**course.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: `
  <h3>Course Title: {{data.title}}</h3>
  <p>Course Description: {{data.description}}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent {
  @Input() data;
}
```

**course-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: `
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of sampleCollection">
      <app-course [data]="item"></app-course>
  </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseListComponent {

  sampleCollection = [
    {
      title: 'Title Course 1',
      description: 'Description of course 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title Course 2',
      description: 'Description of course 2'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title Course 3',
      description: 'Description of course 3'
    }
  ];

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-course-list></app-course-list>
```